# NSPredicate in NSArray, contains number with "/"

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nspredicate, nsnumber

I would like to filter `NSMutableArray` with birthday date of user with Facebook.
Can I use `NSPredicate` ? My NSLog of "result" is :

```
"birthday": "05/24/1993", 
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxx""
```

I would like only "05/24/1993 for getting birthday date and saves that in `NSArray` : birthday.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"/me?fields=birthday"];
    [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result, NSError *error) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:result forKey:@"birthdayDate"];
        self.birthdayArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"birthdayDate"];

        NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] '/'"];
        self.birthday = [self.birthdayArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];

        NSLog(@"BIRTHDAY : %@", self.birthday);

    }
```

and **my NSLog of NSArray birthday is ERROR :**

```
-[__NSCFDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f80a570
```

Comment: From the error it is clear that, `result` object is `NSDictionary` not `NSArray`

Comment: check whether result is NSDictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is an `NSDictionary` instance and not an `NSArray` instance. Thats why you get the error message since `NSDictionary` does not support the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` message.

You can get an `NSArray` containing all the keys from the NSDictionary:

```
NSArray *keys = [result allKeys];
```

Filter the array as you did :

```
NSArray *filteredKeys = [keys filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] 'b'"]];
```

And then use the `filteredKeys` to extract the required value(s) from the dictionary :

```
for (NSString *key in filteredKeys) { // Assuming that the dictionary keys are string
    id value = [result objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Current value for key %@ = %@", key, value);
}
```